# Batch element-wise product in loss function with keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, backend, loss, eager-execution

I am trying to write a custom loss function in keras where I need to weight the MSE between y_true and y_pred (shape: (batch_size, 64, 64)) by the output of an intermediate layer (whose shape is (batch_size, 1)).

The op I need is simply weight (multiply) each batch element of the MSE by a factor, i.e. the corresponding batch element in the weight_tensor.

I tried the following

```
def loss_aux_wrapper(weight_tensor):
    def loss_aux(y_true, y_pred):
        K.print_tensor(weight_tensor, message='weight = ')
        _shape = K.shape(y_true)
        return K.reshape(K.batch_dot(K.batch_flatten(mse(y_true, y_pred)), weight_tensor, axes=[1,1]),_shape)
    return loss_aux
```

but I get

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: 4096 vs. 1: [32,1,4096] [32,1,1] 0 0      [[node loss/aux_motor_output_loss/MatMul (defined at /code/icub_sensory_enhancement/scripts/models.py:327) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_6548]
```

K.print_tensor does not output anything, I believe because it is called at compile time?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In order to weight an MSE loss function, you may use the `sample_weight=` argument while calling the `mse` function. As per the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError),

> If
> `sample_weight` is a tensor of size `[batch_size]`, then the total loss
> for each sample of the batch is rescaled by the corresponding element
> in the `sample_weight` vector. If the shape of `sample_weight` is
> `[batch_size, d0, .. dN-1]` (or can be broadcasted to this shape), then
> each loss element of `y_pred` is scaled by the corresponding value of
> `sample_weight`. (Note ondN-1: all loss functions reduce by 1 dimension,
> usually `axis=-1`.)

In your case, the `weight_tensor` has a shape `( batch size , 1 )`. So first we need to reshape it, like,

```
reshaped_weight_tensor = K.reshape( weight_tensor , shape=( batch_size ) )
```

This tensor then can be used with `MeanSquaredError`,

```
def loss_aux_wrapper(weight_tensor):

    def loss_aux(y_true, y_pred):
        reshaped_weight_tensor = K.reshape( weight_tensor , shape=( batch_size ) )
        return mse( y_true , y_pred , sample_weight=reshaped_weight_tensor )
        
    return loss_aux
```